# library is build correctly but without an .lib file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

I am building a cpp lib using cmake. x86_64
I want a SHARED lib, so I am using shared and everything is building fine without any errors but it is only creating the dll file. I am also using __declspec(dllexport), so there should be one

later on I want to link the lib with my test program but always get the error fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file '..\lib\Release\MQTTClient.lib'

because vs is not creating any lib file ...

anyone an idea?

Comment: Usually that means you aren’t exporting any symbols but you said you’re using `dllexport`. Edit your question to show an example of how it’s used.

Comment: Without passing your export flag, Visual Studio won't export symbols and so no library will be created.
You can as a test, because it is ugly but sometimes needed, use CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS=True
It should export a .lib 
see https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/variable/CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS.html

The first option, passing the Export flag is the best one (the default behaviour is dllimport if you don't precise.)

Comment: thx, the cmake flag was the solution

Comment: @Noki Please consider to transfer your comment into an answer, so mojado can accept it and mark this question solved.

Comment: @Stanley Will be done ASAP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the CMake Flag :

```
CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS=True
```

It should exports a .lib file, with every functions symbols in it.

see the official [CMake Documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/variable/CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS.html) for more details

This flag is pretty useful, especially when you have to deal with 3rd parties, you'll need to pass the flag to CMake when building for Windows.

But it's better to explicitly mark functions, that you want to exports with __declspec(dllexport).
I really don't know what you did wrong

(Comment turned into an answer)